# how to check if value in mongodb is same value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to check value is same external value with mongodb aggregation.I want to use aggregation method find result. Thank you very much.

```
var id = 5995cc31f36d28126e46e670

{ _id: 5995cc31f36d28126e46e670,
  income: [ '23', '23', '232', '', '', '', '' ],
  incomedetail: [ '23', '23', 'ew', '', '', '', '' ],
   outcome: [ '23', '23', '43', '', '', '', '' ],
   outcomedetail: [ '23', '23', 'fsdf', '', '', '', '' ],
  date:
    [ '2017-08-18',
     '2017-08-18',
     '2017-08-17',
     '2017-08-11',
     '2017-08-26',
     '2017-08-26',
     '11/02/2345' ] }
{ _id: 5995d9f8f36d28126e46ed17,
  income: [ '', '', '' ],
  incomedetail: [ '', '', '' ],
  outcome: [ '40', '40', '72' ],
  outcomedetail: [ '23', '32', '32' ],
  date: [ '2017-08-18', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-18' ] }
```

output

```
{ _id: 5995cc31f36d28126e46e670,
  income: [ '23', '23', '232', '', '', '', '' ],
  incomedetail: [ '23', '23', 'ew', '', '', '', '' ],
   outcome: [ '23', '23', '43', '', '', '', '' ],
   outcomedetail: [ '23', '23', 'fsdf', '', '', '', '' ],
  date:
    [ '2017-08-18',
     '2017-08-18',
     '2017-08-17',
     '2017-08-11',
     '2017-08-26',
     '2017-08-26',
     '11/02/2345' ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but maybe this helps you out :

```
function exampleCheck(JSONObj, theID){
 if( JSONObj._id == theID){ return "match"; }
 else{ return "no match"; }
}

var testObj = { 
  _id: 5995d9f8f36d28126e46ed17,
  income: [ '', '', '' ],
  incomedetail: [ '', '', '' ],
  outcome: [ '40', '40', '72' ],
  outcomedetail: [ '23', '32', '32' ],
  date: [ '2017-08-18', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-18' ] 
};

console.log( exampleCheck(testObj, '5995cc31f36d28126e46e670') );
```